# Scanning duplicate file names

Tags: python

Imagine several folders such as

```
d:\myfolder\abc
d:\myfolder\ard 
d:\myfolder\kjes
...
```

And in each folder, there are files such as

```
0023.txt, 0025.txt, 9932.txt in d:\myfolder\abc
2763.txt, 1872.txt, 0023.txt, 7623.txt in d:\myfolder\ard
2763.txt, 2873.txt, 0023.txt in d:\myfolder\kjes
```

So, there are three `0023.txt` files, and two `2763.txt` files.

I want to create a file (say, `d:\myfolder\dup.txt`) which contains the following information:

```
0023 3
0025 1
9932 1
2763 2
1872 1
7623 1
2873 1
```

How can I implement that in Python? Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for files with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not extensively tested, but this works:

```
import os, os.path

dupnames={}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('myfolder'):
    for file in files:
        fulpath=os.path.join(root,file)
        if file in dupnames:
            dupnames[file].append(fulpath)
        else:
            dupnames[file]=[fulpath]

for name in sorted(dupnames):
    print name, len(dupnames[name])
```

This works in the following way:

1. Creates an empty dict;
2. Walks the file hierarchy;
3. Creates a entries in a dict of lists (or append an existing list) with the `base name: [path to file]`.

After the `os.walk` you will have a dict like so:

```
{0023.txt: ['d:\myfolder\abc', 'd:\myfolder\kjes'], 0025.txt: ['d:\myfolder\abc']}
```

So to get your output, just iterate over the sorted dict and count the entries in the list. You can either redirect the output of this to a file or open your output file directly in Python.

You show your output with the extension stripped -- `0023` vs `0023.txt`. What should happen if you have `0023.txt` and `0023.py`? Same file or different? To the OS they are different files so I kept the extension. It is easily stripped if that is your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: use glob.glob to find all the files
Step 2: create a dictionary with each filename's last portion (after the last divider)
Step 3: go through the list of filepaths and find all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import collections
path = "d:\myfolder"
filelist = []
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):

    filelist.extend(files)
filecount = collections.Counter(filelist)
```

Comment: This solution is very nice, but the syntax is incorrect: `filelist.append[files]` doesn't run, and anyway you probably want `extend` rather than `append` (and also you should capture the return value of `collections.Counter(filelist)` otherwise that is a pointless operation).

Comment: it should be `filelist.extend(files)`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't precisely what you've asked for, but it might work for you without writing a line of code, albeit at a bit of a performance penalty.  As a bonus, it'll group together files that have the same content but different filenames:

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/equivalence-classes.html

The latest version is almost always O(n), without sacrificing even a little bit of accuracy.